# How to generate axioms in Description Logic from ontologies using Protege?

Tags: ontology, protege, description-logic

I have just been starting to read about creating ontologies and using Protege. One of the things that I want to do, is given an ontology I want to express the axioms generated from the ontology in a Description Logic format. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any way to do it in Protege?
2. If no, do you have any suggestions of doing it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Protege is doing exactly that. If you `A \sqsubseteq B` in Protege you create class `B` as subclass of class `A`. A good resource to learn how to use Protege is the [pizza tutorial](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege4Pizzas10Minutes). On my blog I have a mapping from Description Logics to Manchester Syntax, which is the syntax used in Protege to specify axiom. See [here](https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/uml-class-diagram-to-owl-and-sroiq-reference.pdf). Also see  [the mathematical formalization of object orientation](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/mathematical-formalization-of-object-orientation/) for some step-by-step explanation of how DLs relate to object orientation, which can help getting a basic understanding of Description Logics.

Comment: Programmatically this can be done with the DL document formats - one for HTML output, one for utf8. There's a LaTeX option too.